# How can I record a pop-up in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am actually new to JMeter.
I have an issue - I have an application (developed in SharePoint) for which I have to load test. So while login, we will get a pop-up where we enter username and password.

The problem here is JMeter is not recording the values that we enter into that pop-up.

Please help me in fixing this issue.

Comment: If this "pop up" is a basic auth, you could throw a view on this blog: https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is common for SharePoint applications. Actually your application is using Windows Authentication method and JMeter can't record this because Jmeter records only web browser actions. You have two options for handling this authentication/scenario:

1. You have to use the **[HTTP Authorization Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager)** for this pop-up. Using this you still will not be able to record that pop-up, but when you playback/run your script, then the credentials used in the HTTP Authorization manager will be used for login and JMeter will get a successful Authentication. This [link](https://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-http-basic-authentication-jmeter) will provide you step-by-step guideline on how to use this Authorization Manager.
   Make sure you use the latest version of JMeter, as I myself faced this issue that Authorization Manager is not working correctly in JMeter 2.9 version (which I had used long time ago with SharePoint application).
2. Another solution is to **switch off the Windows Authentication and trun-on the Form Authentication**. After doing this your application will ask for credentials as other web-applications through a login page. Generally, I have seen that SharePoint applications (which I have load tested) have both Form and Window authentications and later one is given the preference or later one is the default one. But switching to Form Authentication is not a bigger task for Configuration manager/Developers *(they might say no, it will take a lot of time, but trust me it should not a whole day task to do).*
   **Once this is ON** over the server, you are good to go without any issue and Authorization Manager is also not required then. Use this as a backup plan, in case your HTTP Authorization manager doesn't work or creates issues.

I have used this second solution too, when the first didn't work for me.